# Invalid subscript type list, not sure why

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I'm beginning to learn R, and I'm writing a script, but I'm getting a weird error. I have a data frame, and I'd like to take a subset of the columns. I created a variable called meansAndStdevs, which is a logical vector. I want to use this logical vector to subset the columns in my data frame. Here's the code I have:

```
features <- read.table("./features.txt")$V2;
meanAndStdevRegEx <- "(-mean\\(\\))|(-std\\(\\))";
meansAndStdevs <- as.logical(sapply(features, function(f) { grep(meanAndStdevRegEx, f); }));

fileData <- read.table(filePath);
fileDataSubset <- fileData[, meansAndStdevs]
```

However, I end up getting the error `Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'`, and I'm not sure why! I think it might have something to do with my `meansAndStdevs` list having NAs in place of FALSEs. Hoping for some guidance.

Here are the first few items in the features list (it's class is actually "factor"):

```
 features <- c("tBodyAcc-mean()-X", "tBodyAcc-mean()-Y", "tBodyAcc-mean()-Z", 

 "tBodyAcc-std()-X", "tBodyAcc-std()-Y", "tBodyAcc-std()-Z", "tBodyAcc-mad()-X",

  "tBodyAcc-mad()-Y", "tBodyAcc-mad()-Z", "tBodyAcc-max()-X", "tBodyAcc-max()-Y", 
  "tBodyAcc-max()-Z", "tBodyAcc-min()-X", "tBodyAcc-min()-Y")
```

Here is the data in fileData: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MDSilber/CourseProject/master/Dataset/test/X_test.txt

It's pretty large though, so here's some more info on it:

```
dput(fileData[1:5, 1:3])

structure(list(V1 = c(0.25717778, 0.28602671, 0.27548482, 0.27029822, 
0.27483295), V2 = c(-0.02328523, -0.013163359, -0.02605042, -0.032613869, 
-0.027847788), V3 = c(-0.014653762, -0.11908252, -0.11815167, 
-0.11752018, -0.12952716)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "data.frame")
```

This is a table of 561 columns. I'm trying to extract the columns that correspond to the TRUE values of the meansAndStdevs vector and create a new data frame in fileDataSubset from that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the result of your `sapply` call.  It's likely a list and that's what is causing the error.  You can't subset with a list.  If it's a list, wrap it in `unique(unlist(...))` and give it another go

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why it wasn't working. I was supposed to be using `grepl`, instead of `grep`, since `grepl` outputs a logical vector (which is what I wanted). Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I think you don't need the `sapply`. `grepl(meanAndStdevRegEx, features)` would give the logical vector

Answer (score 0):

When I run fileDataSubset <- fileData[, meansAndStdevs], I get the invalid columns error. This is because the logical vector meansAndStdevs has more columns than fileData.  You can take a subset of meansAndStdevs which corresponds to your data, then subset fileData on that basis:

```
datacols <- meansAndStdevs[1:ncol(fileData)]
fileDataSubset <- fileData[, datacols]
```

I am assuming the following setup (showing for clarity because your post has them out of order):

```
fileData <- structure(list(V1 = c(0.25717778, 0.28602671, 0.27548482, 0.27029822, 
0.27483295), V2 = c(-0.02328523, -0.013163359, -0.02605042, -0.032613869, 
-0.027847788), V3 = c(-0.014653762, -0.11908252, -0.11815167, 
-0.11752018, -0.12952716)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "data.frame")

features <- c("tBodyAcc-mean()-X", "tBodyAcc-mean()-Y", "tBodyAcc-mean()-Z", 

 "tBodyAcc-std()-X", "tBodyAcc-std()-Y", "tBodyAcc-std()-Z", "tBodyAcc-mad()-X",

  "tBodyAcc-mad()-Y", "tBodyAcc-mad()-Z", "tBodyAcc-max()-X", "tBodyAcc-max()-Y", 
  "tBodyAcc-max()-Z", "tBodyAcc-min()-X", "tBodyAcc-min()-Y")

meanAndStdevRegEx <- "(-mean\\(\\))|(-std\\(\\))";
meansAndStdevs <- as.logical(sapply(features, function(f) { grep(meanAndStdevRegEx, f); }));
```

You can then see that the sizes of meansAndStdevs and fileDataSubset are different:

```
> length(meansAndStdevs)
[1] 14
> ncol(fileDataSubset)
[1] 3
```

This is why you need to subset meansAndStdevs to use it as an array index.